# How to select specific images for an image collection using metadata properties in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am very new to Google Earth Engine.
I want to create image collections with specific images that I have pre-selected. I think that maybe I should filter by metadata properties - either `date` or `product_ID`. 
It's not working and I need to figure out how to do it for many images.

A basic example of what I have tried:

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filterMetadata(
    'LANDSAT_ID',
    'equals',
    LT05_L1TP_225059_19840826_20170220_01_T1
);
```

or perhaps using `system:time_start` to filter by date in some way.

Answer (score 2):

For selecting by date:

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
          .filterBounds(YOUR geometry)
          .filterDate('2018-08-18', '2019-08-19');
```

For selecting by IDs:

```
var l8= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
          .filter(ee.Filter.inList('LANDSAT_ID',ee.List(['YOUR Landsat ID','YOUR Landsat ID'])));
```

Comment: Thank you this was useful. I also found another solution following this code https://code.earthengine.google.com/e62639c6e1b1c21c6e6ad41c0d2b6399

Answer (score 0):

I feel the answer provided by Lola in the comment section is much more easier.
I am adding in this answer here for other's convenience.

Credits to @Lola,

Directly adding the Landsat images using the ID into an Image collection for each of the image you are interested.

```
var c = ee.ImageCollection([
  ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_225059_20130826'),
  ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_225059_20130911')]);
```